# Downgraded Twisted, now getting: 'scrapy.telnet.TelnetConsole': No module named conch

Tags: python, scrapy

I downloaded the Scrapy example from https://github.com/scrapy/quotesbot.
I'm in a virtualenv with Python 2.7.3 with system site packages.

At first, I was getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'
```

Then, according to https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2473, I needed to downgrade to Twisted=16.4.1, which I did.

Now I get the error in the title:

```
ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy.telnet.TelnetConsole': No module named conch
```

Where to from here?

Comment: Try installing a older scrapy version `pip install scrapy==1.0.0 --force --upgrade` and see which version works for you

Comment: I tried Scrapy 0.16.4 but still the same error. (I'm behind a corporate firewall with no admin privileges so it's a nightmare trying to install scrapy using pip - I used the Scrapy versions available in my company's local repository).